# Display images as jpeg in my application php from S3 bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, twig, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony4

I have a problem displaying images as jpeg in my website from S3 after deploying the application on elastic beanstalk ??

I have a php/symfony backend. I set up a route to retrieve a jpeg file from a private **S3 bucket** using PHP AWS SDK's function getObject().

In local environement i manage to display my images as a jpeg files from my bucket s3, no problem here.

But after deploying my app on aws **ElasticBeanstalk**, Then I get an object returned and my problem starts. The object I receive looks like this:

`????JFIFHH??C  %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(??C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((????"??????vL ???TM?? -9??pF??Zg?%K??f?r??A)??Q?_??V.?$?u/???l?3???%?X:?z??l?\??,?NqSv?,??,???`-?k???U?Q??K7.????%??*?exp<???2@?s???t0<?zs??[????qRL???8?8gM?{k?? èh??]!?????Qm?A-Q??IV?F??j???:??3X??/M?+i??\eU??8a??h?u??%??`;b?' Y??V?F*N2?z&?b??1)W????K S?c?-_??V?=5?L?W??T?sS?nx3??]+??sn?0?G9m??????+ny?+J?1?k?R?-m??????[??e|??S??-?Xo?*>?<???c??c7?-G????kJ82??i?z!??d???dVS;?]]?š?1* ?{??`

Etc... the string is obviously much longer

This is my **Controller.php** to retrieve the jpeg images :

```
  /**
    * Display images from s3 aws 
    * @Route("/test2/{nom}", name="display_image")
    */ 
    public function getFileFromS3(AmazonS3Service $s3ClientService, $nom){
        $s3 = $s3ClientService->getS3Client();
        $sousRepertoire = $this->getParameter('s3SousRepImg');
        $bucket = $this->getParameter('s3Bucket');
        $repertoire = 'dev';
        $key = trim($repertoire,"/")."/".trim($sousRepertoire,"/")."/".$nom;

        $result = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $key
        ]);

        $body = $result['Body'];
        $type = $result['ContentType'];
        
        $response = new Response($body);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $type );

        return $response; // retourne un objet response contenant les données de l'image 
    }
```

And this is my twig that call the result of **Controller.php**, to display the jpeg images in my website :

```
 <a href="{{ path('display_image', {'nom':entity.image }) }}">
  <img src="{{ path('display_image', {'nom':entity.image }) }}" width="70" border="0" />
 </a>
```

It works fine in local environnement but when deploying into aws it dosent ??

I've spent so much time trying to solve this, and it seems like such an easy problem, but I just can't figure it out. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What does `var_dump($result['ContentType'];)` output?

Comment: Hi @DarkBee, thanks...the output is : jpeg

Comment: That should be `image/jpeg` not `jpeg`

Comment: I just fixed the problem. I was deploying the application with the debug mode activated.
Thank you anyway